# Pandas Dataframe index & loc

Tags: python, pandas

I am pretty new to Pandas , and working on an assignment to convert some pandas code to pyspark.

Can someone pls explain me what is below code is actually doing.

There is a Pandas Dataframe named DFF and it looks like below:

```
                    DB
SalesOrder SOItem SLNo    
4500041    10     1     PP
4501034    20     1     ZH
```

This is the Index details of DFF

```
                       DB
SalesOrder SOItem SLNo    
4500041    10     1     PP
4501034    20     1     ZH

MultiIndex([('4500041', '10', 1),
            ('4501034', '20', 1)],
           names=['SalesOrder', 'SOItem', 'SLNo'])
```

There is another Pandas Dataframe named SDD and it looks like below:

```
  SalesOrder SOItem  SLNo    DlvDate  ...  DB  CommittQty ProdOrder CommitQty
0    4500041     10     1 2017-02-16  ...  PP       6,000                 6.0
1    4501034     20     1 2017-02-13  ...  ZH       1,000                 1.0
2    4501034     10     2 2017-02-16  ...  ZH        5,00                 5.0
3    4501464     20     2 2017-02-13  ...  KK       9,000   8500065       9.0

[4 rows x 11 columns]
```

The part of code that I need help with is below.

```
SDD.loc[DFF.index, 'RDD'] = SDD.loc[DFF.index, 'DlvDate']
```

Can someone pls explain me what is being done in the above line of code. I got these two dataframes in Pyspark but unable to understand what to do with that for the above mentioned Pandas code.

I printed every level to debug however couldn't get much understanding.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service. Take a Pandas tutorial to learn about these methods.

Comment: Calm down. I was merely informing you of the rules of the site, which you appeared to not be aware of. If you have a question about the basic mechanics of Pandas, take a Pandas tutorial. There's a good one right on their website, and the documentation is there as well. In fact, there's a free online book called [Python for Data Analysis](https://wesmckinney.com/book/) that I highly recommend for working with Pandas and NumPy.

Answer (score 1):

This is the below action that is being performed with the below code.

SDD.loc[DFF.index, 'RDD'] = SDD.loc[DFF.index, 'DlvDate']

Basically in this above line the following operations are being done.

All the index columns of DFF Dataframe and All the Index columns of SDD Dataframe are joined. A new column is created named 'RDD' on the SDD Dataframe and for all matching index values of DFF Dataframe , SDD.DlvDate column value is set in the RDD column and for unmatched values , null is set.

The equivalent pyspark is left joining the dataframes  where SDD is the left dataframe , then with a "case when then" needs to check if any of the joining col of DFF dataframe is null then set the SDD dataframe DlvDate  as null.